# jQuery sibling divs same height with window resize not working with text wrapping

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, window-resize

I have attached my code below

The issue I am experiencing occurs when **resizing** the window. The text overflows its parent divs and it looks bad. The overflow I am worried about deals with the overflow that appears in terms of **height**, *not width*. The width will be fixed using media queries. **If you resize the window, you will see the height of the divs do not change, even with the resize function pointing to the same function as the document load function!**

Basically I have 4 divs with different heights and I have the code written below in the JS section that makes all the divs the same height. This works when refreshing the page (on document load), however when I resize my browser, it does not work as I would expect it to.

I have included a snippet (below) and created a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/4s0xk715/)

**JS**, **CSS**, **HTML**

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var myFunction = function featurePageSizing() {
    var elements = "#page-slider .featured .featured-text-container";

    var elementHeights = $(elements).map(function() {
      return $(this).height();
    }).get();

    var maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, elementHeights);

    $(elements).height(maxHeight);
  }
  myFunction();
  $(window).resize(myFunction);
});
```

```css
#page-slider {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  margin-top: 4px;
}
#page-slider .featured {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: white;
}
#page-slider .featured .featured-text-container {
  padding: 15px 33px 27px;
}
#page-slider .featured:not(:last-of-type) .featured-text-container {
  border-right: 1px dashed #DCDCDC;
}
#page-slider .featured .featured-text-container .featured-title {
  color: #17513B;
}
#page-slider .featured .featured-text-container .featured-description {
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #51A351;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
#page-slider .featured .featured-link {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -40px;
  text-align: center;
}
#page-slider .featured .featured-link button.read-more {
  position: relative;
  left: -50%;
  background: #62C462;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #62C462, #51A351);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #62C462, #51A351);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #62C462, #51A351);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #62C462, #51A351);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #62C462, #51A351);
  -webkit-border-radius: 5;
  -moz-border-radius: 5;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 7px 17px 7px 17px;
  border: solid #008a05 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
#page-slider .featured .featured-link button.read-more:hover {
  background: #62C462;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="page-slider">
  <div class="featured">
    <div class="featured-text-container">
      <div class="featured-title">
        <h2>Here is my topic</h2>

      </div>
      <div class="featured-description">
        <p>Here is a description of my topic.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="featured-link">
      <a href="#">
        <button class="read-more">Read more...</button>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="featured">
    <div class="featured-text-container">
      <div class="featured-title">
        <h2>Cool stuff</h2>

      </div>
      <div class="featured-description">
        <p>Here is more text that explains this briefly, as you can see the amount of text explaining this one is greater than the others, so the height of this div is the one that the other divs should be using when setting their heights</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="featured-link">
      <a href="#">
        <button class="read-more">Read more...</button>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="featured">
    <div class="featured-text-container">
      <div class="featured-title">
        <h2>Another section exists here</h2>

      </div>
      <div class="featured-description">
        <p>Internet Explorer, am I right?! Haha...</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="featured-link">
      <a href="#">
        <button class="read-more">Read more...</button>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="featured">
    <div class="featured-text-container">
      <div class="featured-title">
        <h2>The Lion King</h2>

      </div>
      <div class="featured-description">
        <p>Come on the Lion King is a GREAT movie! More text is written here too...</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="featured-link">
      <a href="#">
        <button class="read-more">Read more...</button>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help with this is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: P.S. I have looked at other posts that deal with this (which I assume someone will mark as a duplicate) however solutions there did not work. I tried every solution I could find and spent about 2 hours on this. I feel I am overlooking something simple.

Comment: @humble.rumble.6x3 The overflow I am talking about deals with the height of the divs, not the width. The width will be further controlled with `@media` in my css files. I will edit my post to clarify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`display:table-cell` will help you here.

Check this:

```css
#row > div { border:1px solid; display:table-cell; }
```

```html
<div id="row">
  <div>aaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaa</div>
  <div>bbbb bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb bbbbbb bbb</div>
  <div>cccc cccccccccccc cccccccccccccccccc cccccccccccccccccccc cccccccccccccccccc cccccccccccccccccc cccccc</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is why I love this website. Answers are sometimes so simple you overlook them, but someone else thinks of it and it makes your life much easier. Thanks, don't even need jQuery for this solution.